# Trying to replace innerhtml of row with responseText

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the following table in my HTML body:

```
<table>
    <tr id="0">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My httpRequest.responseText returns the following:

```
<td class="c1">c<td>
<td class="c1">a<td>
<td class="c1">t<td>
```

I want to replace the row where id="1" with the results from http.responseText and so I try to do the following:

```
var curr_row = document.getElementById("1");
curr_row.innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
```

However, this results in:

```
<table>
    <tr id="0">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td class="c1">h</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="c1">e</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="c1">l</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above returns a row with what seems to be the original empty cells along with the new cells I want. Why is this occurring? I want the httpRequest.responseText cells to completely replace the original cells.

Comment: You shouldn't use DOM IDs which start with digits, btw, it's invalid.

Comment: Your response text html is invalid your closing to tags are missing the /. So you are actually adding 6 to tags and the browser is auto closing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because your responsetext is not having closing tags

Change

```
<td class="c1">c<td>
<td class="c1">a<td>
<td class="c1">t<td>
```

To

```
<td class="c1">c</td>
<td class="c1">a</td>
<td class="c1">t</td>
```

From where you are getting it in the backend!